# How to get Postgres to do a dblink to another Postgres Database with Trusted SSL Certs

Tags: database, postgresql, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am having trouble setting up two postgres servers to communicate via Trusted, Verified SSL using DBLink.

My setup: 
2x Windows Server 2016 on AWS hosted with EC2
One computer is the "Client", the other computer is the "Server"
On each Server, I have Postgres 9.6. (Installed via the BigSQL Gui installer)

I am trying to get "Client" to do "Verified, Full" SSL with the "Server" via dblink.

Here's the steps I am taking to setup.

"Server" postgresql.conf Settings

```
ssl = on  
..
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'  # The cert that I got from SSLForFree.com
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'   # The private key that I got from SSLForFree.com
```

"Server" pg_hba.conf Settings

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD
# IPv4 local & remote connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
hostssl     all     all     0.0.0.0/0  md5   # new
```

"Client" Computer
I put the Let's Encrypt Root Certificate and CA Bundle in this file.
C:/PostgreSQL/data/pg96/root.crt

The command I am running in "Client" in PSQL.

```
SELECT * FROM dblink( 'dbname=postgres port=5432 host=test.example.com user=postgres password=123456 sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=C:/PostgreSQL/data/pg96/root.crt', 'SELECT now()::TEXT;') AS t(a Text);
```

My error

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  SSL error: certificate verify failed
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It turns out I needed to add the full trust chain in the cert file on my "Server".

I used the comodo 90 day cert instead of the lets encrypt cert.

Heres now I laid out the server.crt on the "Server"

The freshly issued comodo cert ontop.

The 2 comodo intermediate certs.

The root comodo cert

I used this tool to check my chaining. https://tools.keycdn.com/ssl